# Asp.net Core 7 Remove WebDaV Module

Tags: web-config

I want this operation to be done while creating the web config. What should I do in visual studio so      that the remove module is added to the webconfig?

```
`<system.webServer>
  <modules>
    <remove name="WebDAVModule" />
  </modules>

  <handlers>
    <remove name="WebDAV" />
  </handlers>
</system.webServer>`
```

I want it to add this automatically while the webcongig is being created. I do not want to change it manually in the web config. I want this remove module to be added when the WebConfig is being created.